# A elementary question about cardinal arithmetic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

My question is: Let $X$ be a finite set and let f be a function, $f: X \rightarrow Y$ show that $ \# f[X] \le \#X$.

Here is my attempt:

As X is a finite set, therefore there exist a bijective map $ g: X \rightarrow n$ where $ n \in \omega$. And for each $y \in f[X]$ we have a set $y':= \left\{  k \in n: (f\circ g^{-1}) (k) = y  \right\}.$

We define the relation $h: f[X] \rightarrow n, \;\;y \mapsto min( y').$

(1) Functional: Let $\, y \in f[X]\,$, if  $\,h(y) = k_{1}$ and $ h(y) = k_{2}$. So, we have  $k_{1} = min( y')= k_{2}\;\; then\;\:k_{1}=k_{2}. $

(2) Injective:  Let $\,z,w \in f[X], \;z \not= w$ we need to show that $h(z) \not= h(w)$.  A sufficient condition is $ w' \cap z' = \emptyset $. Because, that implies  $min (z')  \not =min (w').$

For the sake of the contradiction suppose that $ w' \cap z' \not= \emptyset \;$ which means $ \exists k\in w' \cap z' $. 
$ k \in  w' \leftrightarrow k\in n \wedge f(k) = w,\; $ and  $\; k \in z' \leftrightarrow k\in n \wedge f(k) = z $, which implies $z = w$ (because $f$ is functional), a contradiction .

So, using a composition we have $ f[X] \preceq X$ , $\; \# f[X] \le \#X$ as desired.

The next question is: Show that if the map $f$ is one-to-one, therefore  $\# f[X] = \#X$. For the second one I don't sure how can I argue in a formal way, I know is almost obvious the answer, but all my approaches are too verbose, some hint.

I have another question about other similar exercise, could I put it here after I'll work a little bit in it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof seems fine, I would add a short argument as to why $y'$ is not empty, otherwise $\min(y')$ is ill-defined. I may also change the definition of $h$. Using the notation $h\colon f[X]\to n$ already implies it is a function. I would write it explicitly: $$h=\{\langle y,\min(y')\rangle\mid y\in f[X]\}.$$

As for the second question. Note that $f\colon X\to f[X]$ is always a surjection. With the assumption that $f$ is injective we have that $f$ is a bijection between $X$ and $f[X]$, and therefore both sets have the same cardinality.

Comment: After all thanks, pretty clear your explanation. Only a question: To show that the set $y'$ is nonempty, is it sufficient to argue that: if $n = 0$ the function $f $ is the empty function and the preimage cannot have other cardinality than $ 0 $ and if $ n \not= 0$ the set X is nonempty (because there not exist a bijection between a empty set to a nonempty one)?

Comment: Jose, no. That is not enough. What you need to argue is that $f$ is surjective on $f[X]$. Therefore the composition of the functions would be surjective from $n$ onto $f[X]$, and therefore these are non-empty. Or you can use some variation of this.